# How to get these methods to work with multi-touch?

Tags: ios, touch, multi-touch

I found this code on a tutorial which pretty much sets a left or right side BOOL to YES if the touch started on a specific side of the screen and then checks when the touch moves to see if it changes sides on the screen in order to make the other BOOL yes.

So I am now trying to implement multi-touch but I am not sure how it would work with the following code? Does anyone have any idea how I would go upon it?

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (touchStartPoint.x < 160.0) {
        touchLeftDown = TRUE;
    }
    else if (touchStartPoint.x > 160.0) {
        touchRightDown = TRUE;
    } 
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (touchStartPoint.x < 160.0 && currentTouchPoint.x < 160.0) {
        touchLeftDown = TRUE;
    }
    else if (touchStartPoint.x > 160.0 && currentTouchPoint.x > 160.0)
    {
        touchRightDown = TRUE;
    }
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    touchLeftDown = touchRightDown = FALSE;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit1:
These are what the bools are doing in the game loop, pretty much what I am trying to achieve is that if there is a touch on both sides at the same time, the TOUCH_INCREMENT will be 0 since the touches on each side will cancel each other out. How would I achieve that? Anyway this is the code I am talking about:

```
if (touchLeftDown == TRUE) {
        touchStep -= TOUCH_INCREMENT;
    }
    else if (touchRightDown == TRUE) {
        touchStep += TOUCH_INCREMENT;
    }
    else {
        touchStep = SLOWDOWN_FACTOR * touchStep;
    }
    touchStep = MIN(MAX(touchStep, -MAX_ABS_X_STEP), MAX_ABS_X_STEP);
    pos.x += touchStep;
```

Comment: This question could be more specific. You should first define exactly how multiple touches should work. Assuming there are two touches such that touch 1 appears on the left, and touch 2 appears on the right, how would you expect the variables to behave? Would both `touchLeftDown` AND `touchRightDown` be `TRUE`? What if there are three touches with 2 being on the left hand side?

Comment: If 1 touch on each side at the same time, both would be YES. It wouldn't matter if there is 2 on one side and 1 on the other, if there is a touch regardless of the number of touches on that side, that sides BOOL will be yes.

Comment: You can get your desired touchStep by just calculating leftTouches - rightTouches at the end of countTouches, but your edit mentions TOUCH_INCREMENT being 0, and I dont see that being modified anywhere, it looks like TOUCH_INCREMENT is a constant.

Comment: Sorry, yes I want the touchStep to be 0 if there is are both touches on each side of the screen at the same time so what would I do in that case?

Comment: As I said, subtract rightTouches from leftTouches at the end of the countTouches method. if the result  (lets call it x) is positive, then there are x more touches on the left than the right. if the result is negative, then there are abs(x) more touches on the right. if x is 0, then there are equal number of touches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make this work without the `touchStartPoint` (i)var. The important thing is to not use `-anyObject` and instead to inspect each touch. The following code modifications might work for you:

```
-(void) countTouches:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    int leftTouches=0;
    int rightTouches=0;

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) 
    { 
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        //just in case some code uses touchStartPoint
        touchStartPoint=location;

        if (location.x < 160.0) {
            leftTouches++;
        }
        else if (location.x > 160.0) {
            rightTouches++;
        }
    }

    //reset touch state
    touchLeftDown=FALSE;

    //set touch state if touch found
    if(leftTouches>0){
        touchLeftDown=TRUE;
    }

    touchRightDown=FALSE;
    if(rightTouches>0){
        touchRightDown=TRUE;
    }

}
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self countTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self countTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    touchLeftDown = touchRightDown = FALSE;
}
```

Here I have created a function that is called by touchesBegan and touchesMoved because they need to implement the same logic. You may see some unintended side effects if `touchStartPoint` is being used in the code somehow.